# Single statement method to remove elements from container

Tags: c++, stl, erase-remove-idiom

Is there a single algorithm that removes elements from a container as happens in the following code?

```
vec_it = std::remove_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), pred );
vec.erase( vec_it, vec.end() );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do it is like jalf has said. You can build your own function to do that more easily:

```
template<typename T, typename Pred> void erase_if(T &vec, Pred pred)
{
    vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), pred), vec.end());
}
```

So you can use

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
// (...) fill the vector. (...)
erase_if(myVec, myPred);
```

Comment: Very neat. Obvious when you see it but wouldn't have thought of it myself. I think I might stick with Jalf's method as you can see what is being used but I'm probably just being a wimp...

Answer (score 5):

You mean like this?

```
vec.erase( std::remove_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), pred ), vec.end() );
```

That's the idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: This is still an algorithm plus a member function call, not a single algorithm call. I would not regard this as improvement over the original suggestion.

Comment: True. The thread title asks for a single *statement* though, and this version lives up to that requirement. But yeah, there's no built-in single function that has the desired effect, but it's easy to compose yourself, like ckarmann's answer shows.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know. Maybe there is. But if there is, then it will be a hell of a statement. Nobody will be able to understand or maintain it. If those two lines do what you want, just stick with them. They are perfectly good.

Comment: jaff's suggestion is idiomatic.  And professional C++ programmer should understand it instantly.